# Fast way to convert a two dimensional object array to a List of custom type

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, list, type-conversion

I have a bi dimensional array of objects as follow:

```
object[,] twoDimensionalArray = new object[,] 
{ 
    new object[] {"columnHeader1", 1, 2, 3},
    new object[] {"columnHeader2", 4, 5, 6},
    new object[] {"columnHeader3", 7, 8, 9}
};
```

Let's say I have a class as follow:

```
public class MyCustomObject
{
    public string ColumnHeader{get;set;}
    public int ValueOne{get;set;}
    public int ValueTwo{get;set;}
    public int ValueThree{get;set;}
}
```

Knowing that I might be processing thousands and thousands of lines with possibly one hundred columns, what would be the fastest and most efficient way to map my twoDimensionalArray variable to a List?

There is the obvious for loop, but I am guessing there is a better way.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I would use pipelining using `yield return` to limit memory consumption. But that depends on what you are trying to do on the consumer side.

Comment: Just `.Select(x => new Whatever { SomeDumbProperty = x.WhoCares });` and move on.  Linq is always the best answer.  And if someone tells you otherwise, smack them in their dopey jaw.

Comment: @Will yes I thought about that, but I am not sure it's the most efficient (don't smack me). I should benchmark this of course.

Comment: *rears back* **smack**

Comment: *I have a **bi dimensional array** of objects* You see... you already have a problem... You are fortunate you don't have a **bi dimensional array of Regex**... Then you would have two problems :-). In general don't use multidimensional arrays in .NET . They aren't really supported by .NET . They simply survive there because they can't be removed, and because in this way young programmers can use them.

Comment: Wait... is that a jagged array or a bidimensional array? Because you mixed the notation there... If it is a jagged array, then everything is good (you only have to change `object[,] twoDimensionalArray = new object[,] ` to `object[][] twoDimensionalArray = new object[][]`.

Comment: If you can modify input array to be binary serialized into byte[], you would be able to change class to struct and use `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]` on it. Then in unsafe context you would use `(MyCustomObject*)yourSerializedData`. However I don't know how strings are stored in C# physically.

Comment: @xanatos it's an object[,] type; here is what I see while debugging: http://i.imgur.com/MTFZXvR.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are asking for the fastest and most efficient way.

The good ol' for loop is the fastest. No doubt about it. But still you should measure with real data.

Two alternatives:

```
    object[,] array = new object[,] 
        { 
            {"columnHeader1", 1, 2, 3},
            {"columnHeader2", 4, 5, 6},
            {"columnHeader3", 7, 8, 9}
        };

    int i, maxI = array.GetLength(0);

    List<MyCustomObject> output = new List<MyCustomObject>();

    // 1 - plain old for        
    for(i = 0; i < maxI; i++) {
        var obj = new MyCustomObject {
            ColumnHeader = (string)array[i,0],
            ValueOne = (int)array[i,1],
            ValueTwo = (int)array[i,2],
            ValueThree = (int)array[i,3]
        };
        output.Add(obj);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(output[0].ColumnHeader);
    Console.WriteLine(output[2].ValueThree);

    // 2 - just the same, with Linq. If you need streaming,
    //     linq lets you return the IEnumerable so you can
    //     do foreach on it
    output = Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0))
        .Select(idx => new MyCustomObject {
                ColumnHeader = (string)array[idx,0],
                ValueOne = (int)array[idx,1],
                ValueTwo = (int)array[idx,2],
                ValueThree = (int)array[idx,3]
            }).ToList();
```